# Cocoa Custom URL Scheme selector not called first time

Tags: macos, cocoa, url-scheme

I am developing a Mac application which registers a custom URL scheme. The application launches but my selector method is not being called so I am not able to parse the URL. After the application is launched, subsequent URL scheme calls result in a call to the selector method.

I had the

```
[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] setEventHandler:self 
        andSelector:@selector(getUrl:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

on `AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching` and now moved it to the `init` method without any result.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, moving the event handler registration to the `init` method did the trick. In my case the URL was launching the XCode archived application instead of the newly archived one.